# Como depurar aplicações ASP.NET ou Webservices no IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service, iis, xamarin

Preciso depurar minha aplicação que consome um Webservice e gostaria de poder depurar o Webservice numa janela do Visual Studio e a aplicação em outra, mas não consigo fazer conexão local do emulador do Android para a máquina local.

Como posso depurar o Webservice que está sendo consumido em minha própria máquina de desenvolvimento ou num servidor de testes?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente é necessário que o Webservice esteja rodando num IIS local. O servidor de desenvolvimento do Visual Studio não permite conexões remotas, apenas locais e o emulador do Android age como uma outra máquina acessando pela rede.

## Instalando o IIS em sua máquina

### Máquinas Windows 7 Home Premium, Home Basic ou Home Starter

- Garanta que seu usuário é membro do grupo de administradores da máquina
- Clique em `Iniciar` e em `Painel de Controle`
- No `Painel de Controle`, clique em `Programas` e em `Ativar ou desativar recursos do Windows`
- Na caixa de diálogo Recursos do Windows, clique em `Serviços de Informações da Internet`
- Garanta que estão marcadas as opções: `ASP.NET`, `Recursos de Desenvolvimento de Aplicativos` e `Ferramentas de Gerenciamento da Web` e então clique em `OK`.

### Máquinas Windows 8 e Windows 8.1

- Pressione <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> e digite `appwiz.cpl`
- Clique em `Ativar ou Desativar recursos do Windows`
- Na caixa de diálogo Recursos do Windows, clique em `Serviços de Informações da Internet`
- Garanta que estão marcadas as opções: `ASP.NET`, `Recursos de Desenvolvimento de Aplicativos` e `Ferramentas de Gerenciamento da Web` e então clique em `OK`.

[image: Serviços de Informações da Internet em Recursos do Windows]

### Usando o prompt de comando no Windows 7, 8 e 8.1

No prompt de comando (pressione <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> e digite `cmd.exe`), digite tudo numa linha só:

```
start /w pkgmgr /l:log.etw /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;
IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;
IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;
IIS-ASP;IIS-CGI;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;
IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;
IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;
IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;IIS-Performance;
IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;
IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-ManagementService;
IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;IIS-LegacyScripts;
IIS-LegacySnapIn;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;
WAS-ConfigurationAPI
```

## Habilitando o projeto ASP.NET para depuração

1. Nas propriedades do projeto vá `Debuggers` e marque a opção `ASP.NET` e marque `Use Local IIS Server`
   <sub>Obs: Você pode precisar desmarcar a opção do `IIS Express`</sub>

[image: Opções do projeto]

2. No `web.config` encontre o elemento `configuration/system.web/compilation` e acrescente um atributo `debug="true"`

```xml
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        <compilation
            debug="true"
            ...
           >
            ...
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

## Publicando o projeto no IIS

### Criando o site para rodar o projeto

- Execute o `IIS Manager`

  - `Painel de Controle` > `Ferramentas Administrativas` > `Internet Information Services`
  - Pressione <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> e digite `inetmgr`
- Configure o website padrão clicando em `Propriedades` como opção do botão direito sobre o site

  - Digite uma descrição
  - Marque a opção `Todos (não atribuídos)` para a configuração de IPs
  - Modifique a porta TCP, se necessário
  - Clique na aba 'Diretório Inicial' e especifique um diretório local para o site
  - Dê acesso de leitura ao diretório

[image: Configuração do site no IIS]

### Publicando pelo Visual Studio

Para publicar o site você precisa que o Visual Studio envie os arquivos compilados/processados para a pasta que você especificou anteriormente. Você pode fazer isso da seguinte forma:

- Clique em `Build`> `Publish` ou `Publish Website` para publicar apenas os arquivos finais
- Crie um perfil de publicação
- Marque `File System` como método de publicação
- Nas configurações marque `Debug`

<sub>Obs: As configurações podem não aparecer em algumas versões do Visual Studio</sub>

[image: Publicação do Website no Visual Studio]

## Conectando o Visual Studio ao IIS local ou remoto para depuração

Se você marcou corretamente o projeto com `Use Local IIS Server` e desmarcou `Use IIS Express` o Visual Studio deve estar debugando corretamente, mas caso isso não aconteça por algum motivo, siga os seguintes passos:

- Garanta que o Visual Studio está sendo executado como Administrador (`Run as Administrator`, nas opções do botão direito ao executá-lo)
- Garanta que o IIS está sendo executado pelo painel administrativo `Internet Information Services`
- Pressione <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> e em seguida pressione <kbd>w</kbd>
- Selecione o processo `w3wp.exe`
- Garanta que `Common Language Runtime` está selecionado em `Choose the program types that you want to debug` ou `Managed Code` em `Attach to` dependendo da versão do Visual Studio
- Pressione o botão `Attach`

[image: Debugando o processo do IIS]